# Import the CSV file `data/brasil-real-estate-1.csv` into the DataFrame `df1`

Tags: python, pandas

This is my code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df1 = pd.read_csv("data/brasil-real-estate-1.csv")
df1.shape
```

or

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df1 = pd.read_csv("data/brasil-real-estate-1.csv")
df1.head()
```

But there is an error:

```
# The shape of your DataFrame should be (12834, 6),not (5, 6).
# 
# Score: 0
#
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: We clearly can't help you without seeing the data.  The implication is that the file should have 12,834 lines.  Does it?

Comment: yes, thats true. its in excel so it has 12,834 rows and 6 columns is that correct? do you have any suggestions? what should I do next?

Comment: What does `df1.shape` print?  Certainly `df1.head()` is only going to have the first few rows.  That's it's purpose.

Comment: hi mister, I already did that but the error is saying:The shape of your DataFrame should be (12834, 6),not (5, 6). and you are going to import and clean the data in data/brasil-real-estate-1.csv. so I did this:

import pandas as pd

# 1. Prepare Data

# 1.1. Import
df1 = pd.read_csv('data/brasil-real-estate-1.csv')

# 1.2. Clean the data
# Perform data cleaning operations on df1
# Add your cleaning code here

# Example cleaning code:
# Remove rows with missing values in specific columns
df1.dropna(subset=['price', 'area'], inplace=True)

Comment: Continuing: # Convert 'price' column to numeric format
df1['price'] = pd.to_numeric(df1['price'], errors='coerce')

# Remove leading and trailing whitespaces from 'area' column
df1['area'] = df1['area'].str.strip()

# 2. Read the CSV file into df1
df1 = pd.read_csv('data/brasil-real-estate-1.csv')

# 3. Check the shape of the DataFrame
expected_shape = (12834, 6)
df1_shape = df1.shape

Comment: # 4. Compare the shapes
if df1_shape == expected_shape:
    print("The shape of the DataFrame is as expected:", expected_shape)
else:
    print(f"Error: The shape of the DataFrame is {df1_shape}, but it should be {expected_shape}.")

Comment: the result is still wrong

Comment: You did not answer my question.  What is `df1.shape`?

Answer (score -1):

df1.head() is to see the first few rows, so what exactly is your df1.shape() printing out?

Also, ensure your rows and columns are 12, 834 and 6 respectively. Also you can use DataTable as well

Comment: This is not an answer.  It should have been posted as a comment.